# NProbability failing to converge

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, probability-or-statistics

I would like to numerically calculate the probability of an event involving a random vector. Specifically:

```
NProbability[(t + e > (t + u)/(t + v)), {t, e, u, v} \[Distributed] 
  MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0, 0}, {{1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1/2}}]]
```

When entering the above code, the output tells me that

> "Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases
>   might lead to a convergent numerical integration"

However, NProbability does not seem to allow me higher MaxErrorIncreases (e.g. `Method -> {GlobalAdaptive, MaxErrorIncreases -> 10000}` is not accepted as valid input).

Comment: If you want to pass options to `NIntegrate[]`: `NProbability[(* stuff *), Method -> {"NIntegrate", Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 10000}}]`

Comment: Additionally increasing the `WorkingPrecision` helps: `NProbability[(t + e > (t + u)/(t + v)), {t, e, u, v} \[Distributed] 
  MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0, 
    0}, {{1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1/2}}], 
 Method -> {"NIntegrate", 
   Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 10000}}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 10]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

direct simulation, of course I suppose  this is doing the same as `NProbability` without the convergence check..

```
n = 10^6; 
Count[RandomVariate[
    MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0, 
      0}, {{1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
       1/2}}], n], {t_, e_, u_, v_} /; (t + e > (t + u)/(t + v))]/n //
  N
```

> 0.408513

p vs log10(n):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just a minor tweak on the comments by @J.M. and @Karsten7...

The problem can be restated as one dealing with just 3 random variables as `t+e`, `t+u`, and `t+v` also follow a multivariate normal:

```
d = TransformedDistribution[{t + e, t + u, 
   t + v}, {t \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1/Sqrt[2]],
   e \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1/Sqrt[2]], 
   u \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1/Sqrt[2]], 
   v \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1/Sqrt[2]]}]
```

> MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 1/2, 1/2}, {1/2, 1, 1/2},
>   {1/2, 1/2, 1}}]

Then one can run

```
NProbability[
  a > b/c, {a, b, c} \[Distributed] 
   MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 1/2, 1/2}, {1/2, 1, 1/2}, {1/2, 1/2, 1}}], 
  Method -> {"NIntegrate", Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 20000}}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 20]]
```

> 0.40829540346347099794

This is a little faster than the 4-variable model but unfortunately still suffers from the same warnings.

Comment: Thanks - this seems indeed helpful. However, when I enter your 'TransformedDistribution' code I don't get the same output (I simply get back the code in function form). I'm using Mathematica 10.1 Student Edition. Is this possibly the reason?

Comment: That's possible.  I used *Mathematica* 10.4.1 Home Edition on Windows 10.