# Conflicting results for numerical probability

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, probability-or-statistics

I would like to numerically calculate the probability of an event involving a random vector. Specifically:

```
NProbability[(X > (Y/Z)), {X, Y, Z} \[Distributed] MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, .5, .5}, {.5, 1, .5}, {.5, .5, 1}}]]
```

When entering the above code, the output gives (after a convergence warning)

> 0.408295

If instead I enter the code:

```
NProbability[(X*Z) - Y > 0, {X, Y, Z} \[Distributed] MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, .5, .5}, {.5, 1, .5}, {.5, .5, 1}}]]
```

I get (also after a convergence warning)

> 0.585629

Why the difference?

*Note 1. The convergence warning message is discussed in another post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136768/nprobability-failing-to-converge). As the accepted answer in the linked post shows, simulations suggest that speed of convergence should not be responsible for this.*

*Note 2. I am running Mathematica 10.2, which seems to struggle to produce symbolic shorthands for TransformedDistribution (see comments [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136793/2254)).*

Comment: That's because the statements `X > (Y/Z)` and `(X*Z) - Y > 0` are not equivalent (negative numbers are involved).  Try it with simulations and you'll get pretty much the same differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`X > (Y/Z)` is not the same as `X*Z - Y > 0` since `Z` is not always positive.

```
NProbability[(X > (Y/Z)), {X, Y, Z} \[Distributed] 
   MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 
     0}, {{1, .5, .5}, {.5, 1, .5}, {.5, .5, 1}}]] // Quiet

(*  0.408295  *)

NProbability[(Z > 0 && X*Z - Y > 0) || (Z < 0 && X*Z - Y < 0), {X, Y, 
    Z} \[Distributed] 
   MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 
     0}, {{1, .5, .5}, {.5, 1, .5}, {.5, .5, 1}}]] // Quiet

(*  0.408295  *)
```

Comment: @EOO - it doesn't assume that `Z > 0`, that assumption would be equivalent to `NProbability[(Z > 0 && X > (Y/Z)), {X, Y, Z} \[Distributed] 
   MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 
     0}, {{1, .5, .5}, {.5, 1, .5}, {.5, .5, 1}}]] // Quiet`  which evaluates to `0.254846`